# Half a SQL Query working as expected, need additonal Query for failures within 24hr period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have kindly been helped with some SQL Query coding, which gives me the results of the Failed Jobs shows on the 'Job Activity' section, but I need help narrowing down the produced results to only show Jobs starting with the name 'MAINTANANCE - BACKUP...'. Here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/2AMk3CWy) to my current code.

For example. I would open Job Activity and check roughtly 6 Jobs starting witht he abiove name. I would note the following columns 'Enabled/Status/Last Run Outcome/Last Run/Next Run' then I would go further into the Job History of each and check the past 24hr for any Failures.

I also need help querying each of the Job History in more depth to produce a 2nd list of all the Job Failures for each Job over a 24hr period.

Please let me know if you require further information or examples of the current Backup Job check I'm trying to report on/automate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT   SysJobs.name as 'Job Name'
    ,SysJobSteps.step_name as 'Step Name'
    ,Job.run_status as 'Run Status'
    ,Job.message as 'Error Message'
    ,Job.exec_date as 'Date Executed'
    ,CASE WHEN enabled=1 THEN 'Enabled'  
               ELSE 'Disabled'  
          END [Job Status]
    ,run_status
    ,exec_date
    ,((SUBSTRING(CAST(next_run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 5, 2) + '/'
    + SUBSTRING(CAST(next_run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 7, 2) + '/'
    + SUBSTRING(CAST(next_run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 1, 4) + ' '
    + SUBSTRING((REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CAST(next_run_time AS varchar)))
    + CAST(next_run_time AS VARCHAR)), 1, 2) + ':'
    + SUBSTRING((REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CAST(next_run_time AS VARCHAR)))
    + CAST(next_run_time AS VARCHAR)), 3, 2) + ':'
    + SUBSTRING((REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CAST(next_run_time as varchar)))
    + CAST(next_run_time AS VARCHAR)), 5, 2))) AS 'next_run_date' 
FROM    (SELECT Instance.instance_id
    ,DBSysJobHistory.job_id
    ,DBSysJobHistory.step_id
    ,DBSysJobHistory.sql_message_id
    ,DBSysJobHistory.message
    ,(CASE DBSysJobHistory.run_status
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'In progress'
    END) as run_status
      ,((SUBSTRING(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 5, 2) + '/'
    + SUBSTRING(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 7, 2) + '/'
    + SUBSTRING(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 1, 4) + ' '
    + SUBSTRING((REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS varchar)))
    + CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS VARCHAR)), 1, 2) + ':'
    + SUBSTRING((REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS VARCHAR)))
    + CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS VARCHAR)), 3, 2) + ':'
    + SUBSTRING((REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time as varchar)))
    + CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS VARCHAR)), 5, 2))) AS 'exec_date'
    ,DBSysJobHistory.run_duration
    ,DBSysJobHistory.retries_attempted
    ,DBSysJobHistory.server
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory DBSysJobHistory
    JOIN (SELECT DBSysJobHistory.job_id
        ,DBSysJobHistory.step_id
        ,MAX(DBSysJobHistory.instance_id) as instance_id
        FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory DBSysJobHistory
        GROUP BY DBSysJobHistory.job_id
        ,DBSysJobHistory.step_id
        ) AS Instance ON DBSysJobHistory.instance_id = Instance.instance_id
    WHERE DBSysJobHistory.run_status <> 1
    ) AS Job
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs SysJobs
   ON (Job.job_id = SysJobs.job_id)
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps SysJobSteps
   ON (Job.job_id = SysJobSteps.job_id AND Job.step_id = SysJobSteps.step_id)
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules SysJobSchedule ON  SysJobs.job_id = SysJobSchedule.JOB_ID
WHERE  SysJobs.name like '%MAINTANANCE - BACKUP%'
AND Job.exec_date >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thank you! I've run the Query, but there are currently no Failures, so no results, can I let you know around 2/3PM please!! This looks really promising.

Comment: OK so the Query works, although still no results due to no Failures, I am about to check the individual Job History for each of these Backups to check the 24hr period. Please see Image here showing all successful and the Jobs I'm about to check in more depth [link](http://i67.tinypic.com/2d0jlnn.jpg)

Comment: Is there a way for this Query to still show the Succesful status on these jobs, so the lsit produced looks like the pic above? along with the indepth checks

Comment: One Job did Fail at 13:01:00 but as the Last Run was Successful, the Query didn't show this

Comment: MAINTENANCE was spelt wrong my apologies, this gives me just the 1 failure I was after! Thank you :) this is the Last Run though, not all subsequent Failures within the 24 hour period